# Change font of Kable in Rmarkdown pdf

Tags: fonts, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to change the font of a kable in Rmarkdown when knitting to pdf? I can find plenty on changing size or bold etc but not on changing the actual font. I would just like something sans serif.

Example markdown doc:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

Change the font in the table below:

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>% head() %>% kable()
```
````

[Default table output font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irUaw.png)

Comment: What is it you want to change? Completely different font family? Remove just the serifs?

Comment: I was thinking different font family. I wasn't aware you could just remove the serifs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Latex [fontspec library](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf), see below.
Note that you can see your available fonts and their names in the Fonts page from Settings.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  \usepackage{fontspec}
---

Change the font in the table below:
## using the Arial font as an example
\fontspec{Arial}

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>% head() %>% kable()
````

[image]