# RMarkdown - different font types in table using kable or huxtable, output to pdf?

Tags: fonts, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Using huxtable, output to html with different fonts for different cells/rows is a breeze. Not so much with pdf.
This is not really a new question, but a specific version of 
[RMarkdown - different font types in table using kable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720299/rmarkdown-different-font-types-in-table-using-kable) and
[Change font of Kable in Rmarkdown pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669991/change-font-of-kable-in-rmarkdown-pdf)

I have used the answer given from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54735453/4927395  to create the output in the image below from rmarkdown  (on my windows pc). Note that the 'environment' code will change the font for the table (the whole table), but that text after the chunk is in the font specified for the table.
Suggestions to fix that? 
Also, I could not get the floating example to work on my computer, which is why it is commented out.
I like huxtable, but haven't seen examples of the font selected for the table (where it is different to the main font) working on the web. Open to exploring other table packages if absolutely necessary.

````
    ---
title: "Reprex selecting font for kable table output to pdf"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Path=C:/windows/fonts/]{SHOWG.TTF}
  \newfontfamily\arialfont[Path=c:/windows/fonts/]{ARIAL}
  \newenvironment{ctable}{\arialfont }{}
  \newenvironment{capctable}[1][t]{\begin{table}[#1]\centering\arialfont}{\end{table}}
---

here is some text

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
#This works, though leaves the selected font active for text after the chunk
kable(head(mtcars), booktabs=TRUE, align = "c") %>% 
   kable_styling(table.envir="ctable", font_size=12) %>%
   row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "gray")
#This next bit doesn't work
#kable(head(mtcars), booktabs=TRUE, align = "c", 
#       caption = "This table floats", table.envir = "capctable") %>% 
#   kable_styling(font_size=12) %>%
#   row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "gray")
```


here is some more text
````

[image: output]

Comment: Development version of huxtable now lets you control fonts in PDF version. https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/105#issuecomment-476961219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, here is how to do this in huxtable (I'm the package owner). You'll need xelatex installed, and the LaTeX "fontspec" package. You’ll also need huxtable version 4.4.0 or above, currently available on github:

```
install_github("hughjonesd/huxtable")
```

In your rmarkdown header:

```
output:
   pdf_document:
     latex_engine: xelatex
```

In an R code chunk:

```
library(dplyr)
library(huxtable)
options(huxtable.latex_use_fontspec = TRUE)

mtcars %>%
      head() %>%
      as_huxtable() %>% 
      set_font("Times New Roman")
```

Comment: This is in the latest version of huxtable now available on CRAN etc?

Comment: For the keen set that want to output to html, and use fonts that may not be available, you will want to specify fallback fonts, which can be done like this, using a slash to escape the inverted commas for a named font containing spaces. `set_font(paste0("Agenda, \"Source Sans Pro\", sans-serif"))` To try and force the browser to download the fonts that you want, add something like this to your style.css file `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro');`

Comment: Yup, it's on CRAN now.